# Is there a standard way to match 2 lists with a custom matching function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I know that a standard way would be

```
(Eq z) => matchLists :: [x] -> [x] -> Bool
matchLists xs ys = xs == ys
```

But I have a special matching function for element which is passed from the outside and I have no control over it.

So what I am looking for is

```
matchLists :: (x -> x -> Bool) -> [x] -> [x] -> Bool
```

(Hoogle says [no](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28x%20-%3E%20x%20-%3E%20Bool%29%20-%3E%20%5Bx%5D%20-%3E%20%5Bx%5D%20-%3E%20Bool))

Would you end up with a custom function with a signature like this or what would you do instead?

**EDIT:**

zip functions don't do what I need since the resulting list has the minimal length out of 2 input lists

**EDIT:**

What do you think of this?

```
--matchListsWith :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> Bool
matchListsWith :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b] -> Bool
matchListsWith _ [] [] = True
matchListsWith _ (_:_) [] = False
matchListsWith _ [] (_:_) = False
matchListsWith matcher (x:xs) (y:ys) = matcher x y && matchListsWith matcher xs ys
```

Comment: There's no reason for `matchListsWith` not to have the more general type `(a -> b -> Bool)  -> [a] -> [b] -> Bool`.

Comment: @Cirdec, that's a good point

Answer (score 5):

Using [Data.Align](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.3/docs/Data-Align.html) we can handle both the zipping and the length issues at once

```
matchWith :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b] -> Bool
matchWith f as bs = and $ alignWith combiner as bs where
  combiner = these (const False) (const False) f
```

This unfolds to the same code as your explicitly recursive function, but using tags from `Data.These` to mark the various list alignments. It also generalizes to many other structures like Trees or Sequences if you generalize the `and`.

```
matchWith :: (Foldable f, Align f) => (a -> b -> Bool) -> f a -> f b -> Bool
matchWith f as bs = Foldable.and $ alignWith combiner as bs where
  combiner = these (const False) (const False) f

data Tree a = Tip | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving ( Functor, Foldable )

instance Align Tree where
  nil = Tip
  align Tip Tip = Tip
  align (Branch a la ra) Tip = Branch (This a) (fmap This la) (fmap This ra)
  align Tip (Branch b lb rb) = Branch (That b) (fmap That lb) (fmap That rb)
  align (Branch a la ra) (Branch b lb rb) =
    Branch (These a b) (align la lb) (align ra rb)
```

So that we have

```
λ> matchWith (==) Tip Tip
True
λ> matchWith (==) (Branch 3 Tip Tip) (Branch 3 Tip Tip)
True
λ> matchWith (==) (Branch 3 Tip Tip) (Branch 3 Tip (Branch 3 Tip Tip))
False
```

(Might as well...)

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Tree a) where (==) = matchWith (==)
```

Answer (score 4):

The hand-written approach is perfectly fine here, I think. If you're not already using some library that happens to have a suitable function for this problem, then I believe it isn't worth adding another dependency just for the sake of shaving off three lines of code.

You can still shave off a single line though:

```
matchListWith :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b] -> Bool
matchListWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y && matchListWith f xs ys
matchListWith _ []     []     = True
matchListWith _ _      _      = False
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
matchList f xs ys = and $ zipWith f xs ys
```

Comment: This might cause surprising behaviour if the lists have different lengths. `and $ zipWith (==) [1] [1,2]` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: That's what I thought too. I don't want it to be True. So I guess I need to keep looking.